# How to find duplicate fields using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table person(id, iin, name, done) and table err_person(id, iin, surname, name). How i can find duplicate values within 'iin' fields. If it exist, copy to err_person table and set flag person.done=1 for these rows.

[person table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NU8m.png)

[desired results: err_person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H60EZ.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "duplicate fields". Normally, people are interested in duplicate values within those fields? Could you clarify your question, please?

Comment: yes, i mean duplicate values within 'iin' fields. I corrected question.

Comment: @JTAG . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

To find duplicate values in a field:

```
SELECT iin
FROM person
GROUP BY iin
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You may wish to nest this query:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE iin IN (
   SELECT iin
   FROM person
   GROUP BY iin
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

And so, to insert this into the `err_person` table you could do something like this (noting that the person table does not have a `surname` field):

```
INSERT INTO err_person (id, iin, name)
    SELECT id, iin, name FROM person WHERE iin IN (
        SELECT iin
        FROM person
        GROUP BY iin
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Finally, a separate query would have to be run to change the `done` field. The problem with a nested query here is that you're updating a table that you're trying to look at, thus a simple effort to use an update query that looks at a subquery will fail - because both are based on the person table. A temporary table might be a better option here.

Comment: How to copy the data to err_person table and set the flag for person.done=1, after that. I want to do it using the Mysql, without using the server